Why Doesn't Changing the Batch Size in Llama Inference Produce Multiple Identical Results for a Single Prompt?
Why does setting batch_size=2 on a GPT-2 model on an inf2.xlarge instance produce two outputs for the same prompt, while trying the same with the Llama model results in an error?
import time
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers_neuronx import LlamaForSampling
from huggingface_hub import login

login("hf_----F")
  
# load meta-llama/Llama-2-13b to the NeuronCores with 24-way tensor parallelism and run compilation
neuron_model2 = LlamaForSampling.from_pretrained('meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf', batch_size=5, prompt_batch_size=1, tp_degree=12, amp='f16')
neuron_model2.to_neuron()

# construct a tokenizer and encode prompt text
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")

prompt = ["Hello, I'm a language model,"]
#input_ids = tokenizer.encode(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
encoded_input = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors='pt')

# run inference with top-k sampling
with torch.inference_mode():
    start = time.time()
    generated_sequences = neuron_model2.sample(encoded_input.input_ids, sequence_length=128, top_k=50)
    elapsed = time.time() - start

generated_sequences = [tokenizer.decode(seq) for seq in generated_sequences]
print(f'generated sequences {generated_sequences} in {elapsed} seconds')

I tried using multiple prompts, but it did not generate multiple outputs for the same prompt.
The error message that occurs is as follows:
ValueError: Model not compiled for batch_size : 1. Acceptable batch_size is one of the following [5]
